# How to exclude files, classes, libraries or packages from dart obfuscation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, obfuscation, dart

I found [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Obfuscating-Dart-Code) about dart obfuscation in flutter, but it only says how to enable obfuscation. I tried looking up in what seems to be the snapshot generator arguments [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/bin/gen_snapshot.cc#L185), but the only arguments exposed regarding obfuscation are:

```
--obfuscate
--save-obfuscation-map=<map-filename>
```

Comment: Why would you only want to obfuscate part of your project? Obfuscation is generally an all-or-nothing sort of deal.

Comment: @Abion47 I haven't had the time to debug it, but my app has some errors when enabling dart obfuscation. I am not sure but it is probably some package I am using, so I wanted to exclude all the packages and libraries (as they are open source anyway).

I come from android where you could exclude classes and stuff with proguard rules.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible to only obfuscate part of your application. I don't recall that ever being requested by a Google team using Flutter, so I would be extremely surprised if this was possible.

Comment: I'm using runtimeType.toString() in my code to serialize some classes and this doesn't work well with obfuscation.  (see caveat at the bottom oof https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate).  
Note that, when obfuscating Android/java, one can control which classes to obfuscate in the proguard-rules.pro file

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is super late, but for whoever that needs this now:

To prevent certain classes from getting obfuscated, add `@pragma("vm:entry-point")` above the class definition.

Doing this will make the class name *survive* obfuscation.

e.g.:

```dart
@pragma("vm:entry-point")
class MyAwesomeClass {
  const MyAwesomeClass(this.id, tnis.name);

  int id;
  String name;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/docs/compiler/aot/entry_point_pragma.md#classes